# how can i get the parameter using window.location.search.substring

Tags: javascript

I have this URL https://localhost/test.html?view=1111&project=1000.
How would i write java script function to fetch the variable project..?

Answer (score 0):

A cool trick is to split your URL with `project=` and take the second element :

```js
const url = "https://localhost/test.html?view=1111&project=1000"

console.log( url.split("project=")[1] )
```